# Setting value in Wysihtml5 Editor is Adding an Extra Iframe each time

Tags: jquery, iframe, wysihtml5

I am Implementing wysihtml5 Editor and trying to set the value of the Editor by the following code:

```
$('#ticketmessage').data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue(newtext);
```

But Each time the value is set for the Editor it is adding an extra Iframe how can I set the value without adding an Iframe.

Thanks,

Manisha Biswas

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue